# Chaining methods issue

Tags: ruby, methods

So I have a CSV that looks like this;

```
This is a test file
,,,,,,,,,,,
1122,Foo,Bar,FooBar
22321,Bar,Bar,Foo
11223,Foo,Foo,Foo,,,,,,,,,
12312/2423/1245,Foo,Foo,,,,,,,,
```

I want to parse it and have the following result in my array;

```
1122,Foo,Bar,FooBar
11223,Foo,Foo,Foo
22321,Bar,Bar,Foo
12312/2423/1245,Foo,Foo
```

My code;

```
class ReadCSVToArray

    def initialize(file)
      @array  =  CSV.read(file)
    end

    def compact_multi
      y = []
      @array.each { |i| i.compact! ; y << i unless i.blank? }
    end

    def item_rows
      y = []
      @array.each { |o|
        if o[0].include? '/';  y << o ; end
        if o[0].is_number?  ;  y << o ; end
      }
    end
end


the_list = ReadCSVToArray.new('/Users/davidteren/Desktop/read_test.csv')

the_list.compact_multi.item_rows.sort.each { |i| p i }
```

So as per above I'd like to chain several methods to get my results.

I have tried various things like;

```
class ReadCSVToArray

    def initialize(file)
      @array  =  CSV.read(file)
    end

    def compact_multi
      y = []
      @array.each { |i| i.compact! ; y << i unless i.blank? }
      self
    end

    def item_rows
      y = []
      @array.each { |o|
        if o[0].include? '/';  y << o ; end
        if o[0].is_number?  ;  y << o ; end
      }
      self
    end
end
```

No matter what I try I can't get it to work.

Comment: What do you mean by you can't get it to work? Is it giving you an error or you're not getting the results you want?

Comment: Part of your issue is that you're not mutating the `@array` instance variable...you're creating local variables in your methods to maintain some sort of state...apart from your chaining issue..

Comment: If you could update your question to indicate the output you *are* getting then this might make it a lot clearer; nobody here is going to copy and paste your code, run it and debug it for you :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with this line:

```
the_list.compact_multi.item_rows.sort.each { |i| p i }
```

This chain breaks down to 4 method calls:

```
the_list.compact_multi
the_list.item_rows
the_list.sort
the_list.each { |i| p i }
```

By returning `self` in your `compact_multi` and `item_rows` methods, you're ensuring that the next method in the chain is sent to your `ReadCSVToArray` instance. But there are no `ReadCVSToArray#sort` or `ReadCSVToArray#each` methods. You probably want to call them on instance variable `@array`.

Comment: they has two underlying issues, even if they return `y` on the item_rows method, the chaining will work but their result will be completely wrong

Comment: You're right. I misread the question as only a chaining issue, but there's a lot more going on here.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = CSV.parse 'This is a test file
,,,,,,,,,,,
1122,Foo,Bar,FooBar
22321,Bar,Bar,Foo
11223,Foo,Foo,Foo,,,,,,,,,
12312/2423/1245,Foo,Foo,,,,,,,,'

result.map(&:compact).reject { |l| l.size < 2 }
#⇒ [["1122", "Foo", "Bar", "FooBar"], ["22321", "Bar", "Bar", "Foo"],
#    ["11223", "Foo", "Foo", "Foo"], ["12312/2423/1245", "Foo", "Foo"]]
```

Please note, that rejecting empties probably should be done more accurate. Hope it helps.

To get this:

```
the_list.compact_multi.item_rows.sort.each { |i| p i }
```

to work, `compact_multi` should return `self` and `item_rows` should return `@array`.

Comment: My issue is not sorting the data, but getting the methods to chain.

Comment: Then return `self` from each method you want to chain, save for the last. See an update.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two issues, the method chaining and getting the right result...

Your right result issue seems to be that you're assigning and building out this `y` array but you're not doing anything with it in any of those methods...

```
def compact_multi
  y = []
  @array.each { |i| i.compact! ; y << i unless i.blank? }
  self
end

def item_rows
  y = []
  @array.each { |o|
    if o[0].include? '/';  y << o ; end
    if o[0].is_number?  ;  y << o ; end
  }
  self
end
```

what exactly is your goal? if its to maintain a result through the `y` array then make that an instance variable and initialize it in the `initialize` method...

As far as your chaining method issue if it's what I think you're trying to do which is unclear by your question then your methods should look like this...

```
class ReadCSVToArray

    def initialize(file)
      @result = []
      @csv  =  CSV.read(file)
    end

    def compact_multi
      @csv.each { |i| i.compact! ; @result << i unless i.blank? }
      self
    end

    def item_rows
      @csv.each { |o|
        if o[0].include? '/';  @result << o ; end
        if o[0].is_number?  ;  @result << o ; end
      }
      @result
    end
end
```